# Precedence of operations - Javascript array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not sure of the order of operations in this Javascript code:

```
  suite.parallel([
        suite.it('makes stuff 1', function (done) {

            done();

        }),
        suite.it('makes stuff 2', function (done) {

            done();

        })
    ]);
```

do each of the array elements get evaluated first (do the `it()` functions run first?) or does the `suite.parallel` function run first?

Unfortunately, this is part of a larger codebase and it's hard for me to test it.

My semi-educated guess is that the elements evaluate first, I can't see it being the other way.

Comment: Yeah, it would seem that `suite.it()` would run first. They would populate the array, and then whatever's inside `suite.parallel()` would accept the filled array to do work on it.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Grammar](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-initializer) it evaluates the inner functions first and left to right, or in your example, top first.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, arguments are always evaluated completely before the function is called. Otherwise it's quite strictly left-to-right.

So what happens step-by-step is

1. `suite.parallel` is evaluated to a method reference
2. The array literal `[…]` is evaluated

   1. Its first element is evaluated, which is a call. So

      1. `suite.it` is evaluated to a method reference
      2. The arguments - the string literal and the function expression - are evaluated
      3. The method is called with these values
   2. The same happens for the second array element
   3. The return values are placed in the array are their respective indices
3. The method is called with the array value.

However, this does say nothing about when those callback functions (with the `done` parameters) will be called. All those `suite` methods might start some asynchronous computation, and when they do, only a look at their documentation can tell you what happens when.